# Arba'a Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Seasonal_drift):

> The mean Hebrew calendar year is 365
>   days 5 hours 55 minutes and 25+25/57
>   seconds long (365.2468 days) -
>   computed as the molad/monthly interval
>   of 29.530594 days × 235 months in a
>   19-year metonic cycle ÷ 19 years per
>   cycle. As the present-era mean
>   northward equinoctal year is 365 days
>   5 hours 49 minutes 19 seconds long
>   (365.2424 days), the Hebrew calendar
>   has a "seasonal drift" in relation to
>   the tropical year of about a day every
>   224 years.

Answer (score 1):

224 = מדינה ומדינה

224 = דרך

Answer (score 1):

> One Purim morning, at the crack of dawn, Rav Chaim Sonnenfeld appeared at the house of his *rebbe*, the *Gaon* Rav Yehoshua Leib Diskin, carrying a basket of *shalach manos*. His *rebbe* asked him why he had come so early.... Rav Chaim answered, "When I was a child I became deathly ill, and my parents added 'Yosef' to my name. I then became 'Yosef Chaim', which is numerically equivalent to the word זריז‎, 'zealous'. Since Hashem has granted me life, I am zealous to attend to the mitzvos as quickly as possible...."

—[Rabbi Yitzchak Sender, *The Commentators' Pesach Seder Haggadah*, 2003, pages 282–3](http://books.google.com/books?id=RZTN12uaEKQC&pg=PA282&dq=sonnenfeld).